# Implement Task Scheduler with two different types of tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, scheduled-tasks

I have Two different 'types' of tasks:

1) Advanced
2) Standard

How to limit their execution to run in parallel only

1 Advanced task + 1 Standard task

OR

0 Advanced tasks + 3 Standard tasks

Right now I`m using [LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/) to limit execution of same 'type' tasks.

But how to implement same thing for 2 'types' of tasks? 
Maybe with [QueuedTaskScheduler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/)...
Example would be great.